# Преобразование wav файла в массив

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Всем привет. Нужно выполнить DFT преобразование wav-файла. Функция имеется, графики строятся(по числовым данным), не понимаю как вытащить данные из wav файла чтобы обработать их. Все вышеописанное реализовано в Qt. Сам Qt не знаю толком, изучаю впопыхах. Помогите реализовать функцию "вытаскивающую" данные из wav файла для построения графика/спектра.

Comment: 15 лет назад делал) там одна формула из википедии в 2х циклах

Comment: Не нашел, если можно - ссылку киньте, пожалуйста:)

Comment: так не сохранилось ничего, я тогда ещё маленький был)
wav это просто значения - читаются они одним циклом.

Answer (score 2):

Сначало надо определить формат файла, частоту, битность и количество каналов.

Если PCM - то всё просто. Например для 16 бит, 44кГц стерео:

пропускаешь заголовок файла, потом двигаешь указатель по 32 бита, 16 с однгого канала, 16 с другого. секундный буфер это 44000 раз так передвинуть указатель. Закидываешь это в моно. Например можно проигнорировать второй канал. Я по какойто формуле миксовал 2 канала вместе.

Для моно звука сишным преобразованием типа (int16 *) получаешь данные для формулы DFT.

https://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread1493544.html (https://www.cyberforum.ru/post7846511.html) почитайте тут

Если там adpcm, mp3, ac3 или ещё что, то надо протажить это через кодек. Библииотека phonon или vlc поможет.

Comment: Попробую что-то запилить. Спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такую шутку:
Имеется структура WAVESTRUCT, которая, как я понимаю, описывает все "приколы" WAV файла:
`

```
char                chunkId[4];                 // Информация о формате файла (RIFF), Содержит символы “RIFF” в ASCII кодировке;
unsigned long       ChunkSize;                  // Размер без  chunkId[4];
char                format[4];                  // Формат потоковых данных (WAVE);
char                subchunk1Id[4];             // Описание параметров WAV-файла (fmt-chunk);
unsigned long       subchunk1Size;              // Размер подструктуры  subchunk1  (16 байт);
unsigned short      audioFormat;                // Аудио формат (PCM = 1);
unsigned short      nChannels;                  // Количество каналов (Моно = 1, Стерео = 2);
unsigned long       SamplesRate;                // Частота дискретизации в Гц;
unsigned long       ByteRate;                   // Кол-во передаваемых байт в секунду воспроизведения;
unsigned short      blockAlign;                 // Размер сэмпла в байтах 16 бит = 2 байта моно, 32 бита = 4 байта стерео (включая все каналы);
unsigned short      BitsPerSample;              // Количество бит в сэмпле. Так называемая “глубина” или точность звучания. 8 бит, 16 бит и т.д. /// битов на отсчет
char                Subchunk2ID[4];             // Символы "Data", начало чанка данных;
unsigned long       Subchunk2Size;              // Размер области данных в байтах;
int             dataSize;
unsigned char data[]; 
//vector<unsigned char> data;
```

Ниже приведена функция main:

```
setlocale(0, "");
FILE *file;
errno_t error;
error = fopen_s(&file, "C:/Filename.wav", "rb");
if (error)
{
    cout << "Не удалось открыть файл\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

WAVHEADER header;
fread_s(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, file);
// Выводим данные из сегмента data

int lenght = sizeof(&header.data) / sizeof(unsigned char);
for (int i = 0; i <  header.dataSize; i++)
{
    cout << i << " " << static_cast<int>(header.data[i]) << endl;
}

fclose(file);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

`
Если вывести все данные из структуры, то там вроде все как нормально.Было добавлено поле dataSize для того чтобы размер массива был нефиксированным и зависел от самого файла.Пугает то, что значение dataSize для файла длиной 5 сек равно 1330007625. Так и должно быть или я что то перепутал?